# YouTube is slow. Should I block XOXO-BLK-1?

Tags: youtube

I have a residential ISP, and streaming from YouTube is barely usable.

I have seen reports online that blocking `173.194.55.0/24` (part of `173.194.0.0/16`, `AS15169`, `NetName:        GOOGLE`) and `206.111.0.0/16` (`CIDR:           206.111.0.0/16`, `NetName:        XOXO-BLK-1`) would fix the issue:

> ```
> iptables -I INPUT -s 173.194.55.0/24 -j DROP
> iptables -I INPUT -s 206.111.0.0/16 -j DROP
> ```

http://www.dslreports.com/shownews/Why-Is-Everyone-Having-YouTube-Streaming-Issues-123282

Does this sound like a good plan?  Won't the internet stop working if people start blocking /16 here and there like that?

Comment: Could you link to these reports?

Comment: There are too many links, the DSLR link I provided has a good summary.  Or should I edit to include all the links from there?

Comment: @cnst - How about you try it since the process can easily be reversed and report back?

Answer (score 1):

Please use [Nelimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/).  This will help you which TCP connection is choking your bandwidth and you can specifically block that particular transaction.  Many at time previous videos or other youtube page elements keep streaming data.

Answer (score 1):

This guide proved very useful/successful for many people in the US:
http://mitchribar.com/2013/02/how-to-stop-youtube-sucking-windows-guide/

Here is a reddit discussion for context:
http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1axwab/you_tube_becoming_a_big_pos_load_times_are/c91qw0l

(the guide is for windows but you can just reference the IP ranges)